# Stackdriver Logging agent - GRPC::Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

So I'm trying to get the Logging agent running on a google instance however when it runs the following error keeps occurring and logs are not being sent over to Stackdriver

```
#0 failed to flush the buffer, and hit limit for retries. dropping all chunks in the buffer queue. retry_times=3 records=100181 error_class=GRPC::Unavailable error="14:DNS resolution failed"
```

Running the authorization scopes yields

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
```

Comment: This feels more like DNS is failing. Are you able to verify network settings in your OS? Are you using a custom image for your VM? Was it working fine before, or a new instance? Have you tried to restart manually the logging agent? 
Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#agent-install) to explain how to restart the logging agent, for Linux and Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python, you'll need to flush out the stdout to avoid log buffering:

```
 sys.stdout.flush()
```